# Spheres in higher dimensions ....

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, constraints

**Original Problem:**
For a given $y$ and $n$, I want to find all $x_i$'s that satisfy

\begin{equation}
\frac{x_1^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}}=y \tag{1}
\end{equation}

while satisfying following **constraints**

1. $x_i\geq0 \forall i=1,\cdots,n$
2. $y \in [1/n,1]$

From geometry, when

1) $n=2$, solution to (1) comes from equation of circle of radius=1 i-e $x_1=\cos\theta$ and $x_2=\sin\theta$

2) $n=3$, solution to (1) comes from equation of sphere of radius=1 i-e $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$

But how do I find for $n\geq4$? I thought of do following

**Reduced Problem**: let $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}=1$. This implies that $y=+\sqrt{x_1}$. Moreover,

\begin{equation}
x_2^2+x_3^2+\cdots+x_n^2 = 1-y \tag{2}
\end{equation}

But how should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original equation can be written

$$\left(\frac{1-y}y\right)x_1^2=x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2.$$

This is the equation of a cone (more precisely, its restriction to the positive quadrant).

Comment: This is precisely eq(2). But the question remains how do we find $x_i$'s ? Moreover, since I have an equality constraint which makes it a non-convex problem. Is this correct?

Comment: @NAASI You choose $x_2,x_3,...$ arbitrarily and then compute $x_1$ by the given equation.

Comment: @ Winter....this implies that for $n=2,3$ we have unique solution but not for $n\geq4$

Comment: @NAASI No, I meant choose $x_2,...,x_n$ arbitrarily.

Comment: @NAASI: it s not true that $n=2,3$ yield unique solutions.